# No Disassemble stage components can recognize the data. Pipeline default: XMLRECEIVE

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xsd, biztalk

I have Biztalk app with 1 send port and 1 receive port(RP). Receive port has default pipeline: XMLRecieve with validate Document= true and picked correct path to my schema (in correct format like that BizTalk_Server_Project1.Schema1, BizTalk Server Project1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b64a0508dbe93103).
Also i have simple xsd schema:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

and simple xml file
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I put the original XML in the Receive Port folder and run the app.
The App took the original XML from the folder but don't put in the output folder.

In BizTalk Admin Console i see two errors.
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
[![enter image description here][4]][4]

Please somebody help me with this problem. P.S I haven't any orchestration, in my simple project.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VNm9.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1mqe.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dx75F.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k77yv.png

```
<!--xsd schema-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xs: schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="MyTargetNameSpace...etc"
xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns="http:/MyServersName...etc"
xmlns:ns0="http://MyServersName...etc">
    <xs:import namespace ="http://MyServersName...etc" schemaLocation=".\SchemaEnvelope1.xsd"/>
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <b:references>
                <b:reference targetNamespace = "http://MyServersName..SchemaEnvelope1"/>
            </b:references> 
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:element name="Car">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Color" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>

<!--xml document-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Car xsi: noNamespaceSchemaLocation="CarTestSchema1.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www,w3,org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Color>Red</Color>
</Car>
```

Error

> There was a failure executing the receive pipeline: "Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelnes.XMLReceive, Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelnes,
> Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neural, PublicKeyToken =*****d364e35" Source:"XML disassembler" Receive Port:"ReceivePort1"
> URI:"Path to receive xml file" Reason: No Disassemble stage components can recognize the data.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 mistakes.

1. I wrote Path to my schema in receive port incorrect. I forgot to write the name of my schema.
2. I didn't write xmlns in my XML document. Didn't relationship between XSD schema and XML doc.